# Optimal WP7 bitmap drawing with XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, bitmap, xna-4.0

I want to display a bitmap on a WP7 in vertical position, but it rotates it 90 degrees and coordinates are in landscape position. Is it possible to make WP7 display everything in vertical mode and make coordinates starting from top left corner in vertical mode? If not, whats the best way to display my bitmaps in vertical mode? Should I rotate my bitmaps when I design them, or should i use rotation in my drawing functions? I use XNA spriteBatch.Draw to draw my bitmaps, but it has some advanced rotation techniques that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNA apps are based on the assumption that the game will be displayed in landscape mode. Whether it's easier/better for you to rotate things at design time or when displayign them in the app will depend on various factors, including: what the game does; your preferences; the number of items; the impact on movement calculations; etc...